# Get entity record values from Audit Details Response

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Auditing of an entity is enabled,I want the entity record after deletion.So
I was trying to get that from audit entity records,like this:

```cs
RetrieveAuditDetailsRequest request = new RetrieveAuditDetailsRequest();
request.AuditId = _selectedId;
RetrieveAuditDetailsResponse response = (RetrieveAuditDetailsponse)_orgService.Execute(request);
EntityReference ObjectId = (EntityReference)response.AuditDetail.AuditRecord.Attributes["objectid"];
string ObjectName = ObjectId.LogicalName;
Guid Id = ObjectId.Id;
ColumnSet col = new ColumnSet(true);
Entity ent = _orgService.Retrieve(ObjectName,Id,col);
```

Its throwing an error "Expected non empty Guid".
FYI, I want this record values because I want to restore/recover record by creating it again.

Please help whats wrong with it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to retrieve the deleted record with this code:

```
string ObjectName = ObjectId.LogicalName;
Guid Id = ObjectId.Id;
ColumnSet col = new ColumnSet(true);
Entity ent = _orgService.Retrieve(ObjectName,Id,col);
```

This will fail with the error you are getting because no such record exists (it is deleted.) Unlike CRM 4 and earlier there are no soft deletes in 2011, once deleted it is gone from the database.

Replace it with the following code:

```
RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest retrieveRequest = new RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest();
changeRequest.Target = new EntityReference(ObjectName, Id);

RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse response = 
   (RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse)_orgService.Execute(retrieveRequest);

if (response.AuditDetailCollection != null)
{
var auditDetails = response.AuditDetailCollection;

// Do work
}
```

You then enumerate through the `auditDetails` to get the correct attributes.

You can find more at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/05/23/recover-your-deleted-crm-data-and-recreate-them-using-crm-api.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but its throwing an error : `The entity with a name = 'new_projectdetails' was not found in the MetadataCache.`

while fetching `response`.

Comment: Got it,it seems not a audit record for entity record delete. otherwise its working.

Comment: Are you saying you deleted the entity definition from CRM? Not just a specific record. If you have deleted the entity definition from CRM that is not audited and there is no metadata to use in reconstructing the entity from its Audit log entries.

Comment: no no.sorry for the confusion..Some Audit records were created while deleting some attributes of custom entities(in this case `new_projectdetails`). In this case data recovery throwing this error(may be because of what you have said).In case of those audit records created while deleting any entity record, its working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The "Expected non empty Guid" error is thrown whenever you try to retrieve something with an empty GUID (Guid.Empty, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).  I'm guessing your _selectedId is not set to an actual GUID.  Maybe you're setting it from a Nullable GUID and you are calling ValueOrDefault(), which is resulting in it getting set to the empty Guid, and failing in your Request?

Comment: Hi Daryl, first thanks for your help.just checked,not `_selectedId`,but `ObjectId.Id` is empty Guid. Guid of a reference is null,how is this possible?

`ObjectId.LogicalName` is having correct value.

Comment: @TamalKantiDey I haven't worked with Audit data before so I can't help you out more. I would suggest taht you reword your question now that you know what is wrong specifically.